# Enabling control if array controller has more than 1 element

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I need to have a least 1 element in a particular list.

So ideally I'd like to bind the enablement of the **Delete** button for this list to the Array Controller that provides the contents of this list and disable the **Delete** button for *less than 2 elements*.

I realize that I can easily disable the button if the list is empty via `selectedObjects.@count` -
but is it possible to express the above condition using *vanilla bindings* without a custom value transformer, custom properties or the like..?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but might work:

Bind the Enabled binding to the array controller, controller key "selection", model key path "self". Use the `NSIsNotNil` transformer, which will always be false. Then for the No Selection, Not Applicable, and Null placeholders, select No. For the Multiple Values placeholder, select Yes. For good measure, it's probably best to set the array controller to always use the Multiple Values placeholder when multiple items are selected.

But, really, just make the custom transformer and use that.

Comment: Yep, sounds pretty awkward ;-) Thanks for the suggestion anyway - Basically I was hoping that there was some hidden, magic feature (like extended Collection Operators supporting simple calculations) that would 'just work'